# How Can I Change DBChart Series Marks Font RunTime?

Tags: delphi, fonts, charts, series, delphi-xe4

How Can I Change DBChart.Series.Marks.Font RunTime? I want to assign it a component font like a label font directly:

```
DBChart1.Series[0].Marks.Font := Label1.Font;
```

It is a TTeeFont Class Font. how can i cast my standard fonts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign the font for instance by using `Assign` method:

```
DBChart1.Series[0].Marks.Font.Assign(Label1.Font);
```

Comment: thanks. it seems that Assign Command Copies the properties of another TFont object. More About Assign Command:  Call Assign to set the properties of the font to match the characteristics of the Source object.If Source is another TFont object, Assign matches the font characteristics of the source. Assign does not copy the PixelsPerInch property, so this method can be used to copy screen font to printer font

If the Source parameter is not another TFont object, Assign calls the inherited method so that the font can be copied from any object that can assign font properties in its AssignTo method.

Comment: The `TTeeFont` class is a `TFont` descendant and if you call `TTeeFont.Assign`, nothing but a fallback to the ancestor's `TFont.Assign` happens there in this case. The `TFont.Assign` method knows how to copy the font object and since there is nothing what the `TFont` object could offer to the `TTeeFont`, it is the `TFont.Assign` which takes care of this copy.